How to add more products in row in product category page
Magento version 2.4.7
My requirement is that I want to modify the product category page so that it can display 5 products per row. The default is to display only 4 products. I have tried all the solutions I can find,included ChatGPT, but all are faile.
I would like to ask if there any verified solution for 2.4.7 version?

borrow a image from anther same question.

You can achieve this by adding a css width property to the following li element class in your CSS file or via Admin. This adjustment will display 5 products on the product category page. For example if you were using luma then below code will work
.page-products .products-grid .product-item {
    margin-left: 2%;
    padding: 5px;
    width: calc((100% - 8%) / 5);
}



it didn't work.

Updated the answer with Image. I believe you were not adding css correctly. Try adding it in Admin -> Content -> Design -> configuration -> Active Theme -> Html head section -> Script and Css section

Thank you very much, it is working very well now,  you're right, i was adding it to a css file.

Great, If the solution meets your needs, kindly consider accepting the answer.

For 5 product in 1 row you need to set 1column layout
https://prnt.sc/PgxfT30t3yz1
Thank You!

Thanks,  1column layout can display 5 products in 1 row.  but i still want to use the default layout.
